# Find 3rd point of triangle given two points and one angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have the following problem. I want to find the position of a point $(x, y)$ on a 2D Plane, by knowing three fixed points ($A$, $B$ and $C$) and two angles ($\alpha$, $\theta$). The angles are between the unknown point ($U$) and the known points.

[image: picture 1]

My first intuition was to set up a system with two formulas, one for each of the angles, and then solving it. I am pretty sure this will result in two possible results, but I don't need to worry about that. I have tried solving it, but had no idea how I could solve it.

My second thought was more of a guess, if it was possible to solve it by using circles, that would always create a specific angle along the edge (shown in the lower diagram on picture 2). [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Ec0.jpg) I would then just find the intersection of the circles and have the missing 4th point. Is that a valid option as well?

Is there an easier way to calculate the point ($U$) other, than how I wanted to do it?

Comment: Regarding your picture 2 and the locus given by the angle $\beta$ there, the full locus would also include another circular arc on the opposite side of the chord. (Like the outer edge of [the union Venn diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Venn0111.svg) for $\beta < 90^\circ$)

Comment: @Anouk_S: I believe your words are not enough to show your effort. There are many possible ways of finding missing point: 1) using cosine law to find distances of 4th point from first 3 points; 2) using cosine law in dot product; 3) using circles intersection; 4) using complex numbers and so on. Answer must be the same, that's why calculation complexity of all these solutions will be approximately the same.

Comment: @Anouk_S: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please note that deleting and reposting a question is not the appropriate way to bring more attention to it. (For one thing, deleting keeps people from seeing potentially-useful insights provided in comments.) Moreover, deleting to circumvent closure is against community guidelines. You should simply have edited the previous version (which you did) and waited for the community to vote to reopen the question. ... I'm voting to close this question as a re-post of a previously-closed question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a re-post of [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4500327/409), which had been closed by the community.

Comment: @Blue: That other question has been removed, so you can retract your close vote.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: From what I can tell, the other question was deleted by OP after it was closed by the community, and its edited contents were then reposted here. That's not how things are supposed to work.

Comment: @Blue: Sorry, I just ceated this account and posted my question but someone commented, that I should add some more details about the problem and my solutions. I then edited the post , meanwhile the post was closed because it was missing what I edited in that time. I just was confused because it was closed while I was editing what was missing. And then I deleted it because I wasnt sure what is going on. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your calculation, you'll only get the cosines of the angles, i.e.
$$\cos\alpha = \frac{(U-A)(U-B)}{|U-A||U-B|}$$

Anyway, even if the resulting equations are correct, IMHO this is a dead end because the system of equations will be a mess (two equations of degree 4 in two variables).  What you can do is following the compass + straight-edge construction:

Suppose you have a line $AB$ and a circular arc $k$ above that line.  Then every triangle $\Delta ABK$ where $K$ lies on $k$ has the same angle at $K$: $\angle AKB=\gamma=\mathrm{const.}$ If $M$ is the center of $k$, then $|MA|=|MB|$ and the angle at $M$ is $2\gamma$: $\angle AMB=2\gamma$. Hence a construction would proceed as follows:

1. Construct the center $M$ of $k$ above $AB$.  (Similar for the center $M'$ of $k'$ above $BC$).
2. Draw the circles $k$ and $k'$ which will intersect in 2 points: One intersection is $U$ and the other is $B$.  Due to symmetry, $U$ is the reflection of $B$ at the line $MM'$ that runs through the two centers, hence no need to solve a quadratic equation.

### 1. Finding the Center of Circumcircle

In order to construct $M$: Let $D = (A+B)/2$, i.e. the middle of $AB$.  Then $M$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.  This is a line through $D$ that's perpendicular to $AB$.  The triangle $\Delta MAD$ has the following angles: $\angle MDA=90^\circ$, $\angle DMA=\alpha$ and $\angle DAM=90^\circ-\alpha$.

The following plot shows a triangle $ABC$ with circumcircle around $M$.  All angles have same measure: $|\alpha|=|\beta|=|\gamma|=|\delta|$ where $\alpha$ is located between $AM$ and the line through $A$ that's perpendicular to $AB$.
[image: Angles at triangle ABC and center of the circle]

The equation of the bisector is
$$b:(A+B)/2+\lambda x^\bot \tag 1$$
with $x=B-A$ and where $\bot$ stands for *perpendicular*.
The line $\ell$ on which lies $AM$ is $AB$ resp. $x$ rotated by $\phi=\pi/2-\alpha$:

$$\ell : A+\lambda R_\phi\, x\tag 2$$

where $R_\phi$ is the rotation

$$R_\phi = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi & \sin\phi\\-\sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}$$

The center $M$ of $k$ is the intersection of $b$ and $\ell$:

$$(A+B)/2+\lambda_b x^\bot = A+\lambda_\ell R_\phi\, x$$

This is a linear system of two equations in two unknowns $\lambda_b$ and $\lambda_\ell$. One way to solve is to multiply with $x$ which is perpendicular to $x^\bot$ and hence eliminates $\lambda_b$:

$$(A+B)x/2 = (A+\lambda_\ell R_\phi\, x)\, x$$

$$\lambda_\ell = \frac{(A+B)x/2 - Ax}{(R_\phi\, x)\, x} =\frac{x^2}{2(R_\phi\, x)\, x}\tag 4$$

The right side only depends on $x=B-A$ and $\alpha$. Then plug $\lambda_\ell$ into $(2)$ to find $M$.

Do similar calculation to find $M'$ from $B$, $C$ and $\theta$.

### 2. Intersecting circles $k$ with $k'$ is easy

and no need to solve quadratic equations:
Let $M$ and $M'$ be the centers of the circumcircles.  The two circles intersect in the known point $B$ and the unknown point $U$. Due to symmetry, $U$ is the reflection of $B$ at the line $MM'$:

$$B = M + \lambda m + \beta m^\bot\tag 5$$

$$U = M + \lambda m - \beta m^\bot\tag 6$$

with $m=M'-M$. To get $\lambda$, multiply $(5)$ with $m$. To get $\beta$, multiply $(5)$ with $m^\bot$:

$$\begin{align}
\lambda &= \frac{(B-M)}{m^2}\cdot m \\
\beta &= \frac{(B-M)}{m^2}\cdot m^\bot
\end{align}$$

Then plug $\lambda$ and $\beta$ into $(6)$ to get $U$.

### The solutions

For reference, here are the 2 solutions I found using a small script. You get 2 solutions becaue you can relabel the points and angles: $A\leftrightarrow C, \alpha\leftrightarrow \theta$. `Mi` are the centers of the circles. `U` is the solution and `wi` are the angles as computed form the solution to check that the calculation is correct.

```
M1 = [5.0, 2.0]
M2 = [7.0, 4.2997924617902905]
U = [7.832203217218424, 3.406636035503715]
0.7853981633974483 = pi * 0.25
0.9599310885968811 = pi * 0.3055555555555555

M1 = [7.0, 5.7002075382097095]
M2 = [3.0, 6.0]
U = [6.11554387547106, 6.5416515115965]
0.9599310885968814 = pi * 0.3055555555555556
0.785398163397448 = pi * 0.2499999999999999
```

I dropped the code here https://pastebin.com/umjVNzYr so you can play around.  The very code is in functions `center` (step 1.) and `intersect` (step 2.).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Picture]

Let $O_1$ is center of circumcircle around $ABO$ and $O_2$ is center of circumcircle around $CBO$. And let $D$ is middle of $AB$ and $E$ is middle of $BC$. Then $\angle AO_1D=\alpha$, $\angle BO_2E=\theta$.

Vector $DO_1$ is vector $AD$ rotated 90$^\circ$ clockwise and scaled by $\cot \alpha$. Then $O_1$ has following coordinates

$$x_{O_1}=\frac{x_A+x_B}{2}+\frac{y_B-y_A}{2}\cot\alpha, y_{O_1}=\frac{y_A+y_B}{2}+\frac{x_A-x_B}{2}\cot\alpha$$

The same consideration for $O_2$ gives:

$$x_{O_2}=\frac{x_B+x_C}{2}+\frac{y_C-y_B}{2}\cot\theta, y_{O_2}=\frac{y_B+y_C}{2}+\frac{x_B-x_C}{2}\cot\theta$$

Triangle $BO_1O_2$ is congruent to $OO_1O_2$ then $O$ is symmetric to $B$ with respect to $O_1O_2$.

Then $$\overrightarrow{O_1O}=2\left(\frac{\overrightarrow{O_1B}\cdot \overrightarrow{O_1O_2}}{\overrightarrow{O_1O_2}\cdot \overrightarrow{O_1O_2}}\right)\overrightarrow{O_1O_2}-\overrightarrow{O_1B}$$

$$x_O=2x_{O_1}+2k(x_{O_2}-x_{O_1})-x_{B},y_O=2y_{O_1}+2k(y_{O_2}-y_{O_1})-y_{B}$$
$$k=\frac{(x_B-x_{O_1})(x_{O_2}-x_{O_1})+(y_B-y_{O_1})(y_{O_2}-y_{O_1})}{(x_{O_2}-x_{O_1})^2+(y_{O_2}-y_{O_1})^2}$$

Comment: I was not right, when I wrote that all ways of solution have approximately the same complexity. This way uses several standard steps, which make it easier.